# can I run selenium 2 on real browser without webdriver?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can I run Selenium 2 test cases (using Java) on a real browser (ex. Firefox) without using webdriver?

I would like to test the behavior on a real browser.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Selenium 2 uses a "real" browser to execute your tests. The `Webdriver` is only to `control` the browsers (e.g. open a page, click on a button). However you also can test it in "remote mode" where no "real" browser is used.

Comment: The web application that i test is having what is called an "action listener", once I click on a link that open a new page, it called a java function that do a certain actions.
These is working fine when I test manually but it don't work with webdriver. It just open the page.

Comment: Then maybe your Selenium Test is broken and is not working properly. Without any details it is hard to give any advise...

Comment: clarification:  "remote mode" still requires a real browser.. but it will be located on the remote machine.